# Azure log alert rule created successfully with ARM template but not appearing in portal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template, azure-monitoring

I have created a few ARM templates for deploying Azure metric alert rules, but I now have a requirement to deploy a log alert rule (i.e. a rule based on an Application Insights query rather than a platform metric).

I have scripted the template following the [example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/alert-log?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json#managing-log-alerts-using-azure-resource-template) (which suggests I need to create a resource of type `Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules`) and deployed using Azure portal's Template Deployment service as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy-portal#deploy-resources-from-custom-template).

Azure reports the deployment as successful, and the activity log gives me the deployment result, including the ID of my new resource e.g. `/subscriptions/[subscription-id]/resourcegroups/[alerts-resource-group]/providers/Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules/Custom errors spike alert`.

However, when I navigate to the Monitor blade in subscription [subscription-id], and filter down by resource group [alerts-resource-group] I don't see my new alert.

As a sanity check I created a metric alert using the same process targeting the same App Insights resource, and this one does show up in the Monitor blade.

I guess my question is, am I misunderstanding something about log-based alert rules? For example, does an Azure 'resource' of type `Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules` equate with alert rules of signal type **Log Search** in *Monitor / Alerts / Manage alert rules*? I'm confident my template is correct because it passes validation and completed successfully. But I'm baffled about where the alert rule is ending up!

One thing I should mention is that I'm creating the alert rule in a different resource group to the App Insights instance itself, but this is also true of the metric alert so assumed this wasn't significant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out log alerts require a *hidden link* to the resource they're monitoring. Otherwise they get created but not listed anywhere in the portal.

In my case I added the following variable to the template:

```
"linkToAiResource" : "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('appInsightsResourceName')))]"
```

Then included this as a tag in the resource definition like this:

```
"tags": {
    "[variables('linkToAiResource')]": "Resource"
}
```

Once redeployed the alert rule appears in the portal's Monitor blade.

Comment: Thanks for your post, there is really a lack in the template reference documentation of Azure Resource Manager.